# Android Jump game: A.I. to generate levels according to set of rules

Tags: android, design-patterns, game-engine

I'm making an Android game like doodle jump.
So far I create each level randomly, using a percentage of different kind of platforms that I want:

f.e.

- Level 1: 100% stable platforms
- Level 2: 80 % stable platforms, 20% breaking platforms
- Level X: 40 % stable, 10% stable but dissolve after jump, 10% stable but moving, 20% breaking, 10% exploding, 10% moving vertical 
  etc.

Right now, I create the right amount of each kind, shuffle them, then I loop through the list to catch any inconsistencies. Like if there's two breaking platforms after each other and I can't jump from one to the other.
I also place objects on platforms to jump higher. 
If there's an object, the following  platform should be farther apart.

It all works but it's simply hacked together and gets more complicated the more things I want to add.

Is there a way to solve this with A.I.? Something where I could have a set of rules and it would generate a random platform/object combination respecting those rules?
Can somebody point me into the right direction?

**EDIT**

One case I don't see the state machine solution working is, when I create the formation: stable, cracked, stable and I can't reach platform 3 from 1. Then I would have to add a spring to platform 1 but when creating the first platform I don't have any knowledge about the next state. Any ideas?

Let's say I'm in a state and have 3 different transition options: what are the transitions in my case? Would I have to pick the next state randomly and check if that's an option (according to my percentages)?

@Carlos: you said:"the collection of objects, that can be sorted into categories, so the rules could be category-oriented". 
what do you mean by that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

About object generation, for sure you have to change your approach, since that's too much model-logic in the controller, and more important, since that logic could change and you will get crazy to change it and test everything again.

What i would do is a class that will act as an object factory. Inside of it, you will have an state machine, this is, a collection of variables that represent the current state, and a series of rules that define what can happen next.

In a first a approach, thinking about your platforms, i would have:

- an init function, that receives some values, such as the kind of objects you will need, and how many of each (proportional of absolute values, as you prefer)
- the collection of objects, that can be sorted into categories, so the rules could be categoy-oriented * (see below)
- a sort of flags and variables, defining the restrictions of your model, for instance, considering what you mentioned

  - which was the last object or its category
  - whats the current distance (in number of objects, px, or whatever you need) to the last object of each category (so we can check when in case there is some restrictions about distance)
- tables representing relations between object, such as:

  - immediately after *this* one, it is not alowed *that* one
  - after *this* one, it is not allowed *that* one, for at least *this* distance
- A function the receive a request, consider restrictions from flags and relations, serve a valid object, update flags, and mark that object as already served. Or don't serve anything if there isn't any object left.

So, when you are building the world, you don't need to make a random array and then sort everything with  hard-coded logic, instead you ask the factory to init itself, and then in a loop, you keep asking  for the next object,  which you are sure that is a valid one.

Then, if you change or add new the logic or the restrictions, you only need to update the structures you already have, adding or modifying entries.

Even more, you can try to build a human-readable file, such as xml, where you define the collection of objects, and the restrictive relations between them, and then build an engine to parse it and transform it into java data structures, so you can change that logic in a really friendly manner.

With this you can build a really scalable and easy to maintain code.

**UPDATE:**

**When you have an object that could need a modification depending on which are the next ones**, you can afford it in two ways (first that come to my mind):

1. Start from the last platform and go backwards. Since you keep track of the full history, you know that platform **n** was stable, **n-1** was cracked, so **n-2** has to be stable with spring. Of course you have to find a way to put this rules in any kind of table, so you can automatize it with the rest of rules. I recommend to do it in paper.
2. Other posible thing is that you serve the objects, not one by one, but probably holding some of then when there is a reason to suspect that you will depend on the next ones. But this will be tricky and you can get crazy.

---

**When you are designing your rules, and you see that most of the things are allowed**, do not complicate yourself: you can create the rules as a list of exceptions, i mean, the next state could be any one, meanwhile there isn't in your table of rules anything than explicitly forbids it.  Also, you can mix the two kind of rules. For example, if for one kind of object, everything is allowed but one thing, you can put that rule in the table of forbidden things. If for other element, instead, almost everything is forbidden, you can put the allowed things in the table of allowed things. 
This way, when you are going to serve the next one, you llok at your current status, and then, you check the two tables:

- if there is anything in the table of forbidden things, you select something that IS NOT there.
- if there is anything in the table of allowed things, you select something that IS there.
- If there isn't anything in any of the tables, you can select anything.

---

When you have more than one possibility, you chose any of the available object. Remember that you generated the full  collection at the beginning, according to the percentages, so any one that you choose at this point, will also accomplish your cardinality rules.

Also, keep in mind that this can lead you to a final blocking situation: when you are close to the end, and so you are running short of remaining objects, probably you can find that no one of the available objects is valid. At this point you can decide to

1. simply discard the last element (if its not important if there is, lets say, 49 or 50 platforms )
2. <strike>or you can send them to the controler so it can put them in the middle of the others</strike> (i dont recomend this since you will be repeating logic),
3. or you can change the way you serve the objects: keep them in the factory until everything is build, so you can insert the remaining objects and then return the full list
4. change the remaining objects to other of an allowed type in that point, probably some of the more neutral kind of element.

---

*About when i said

> "the collection of objects, that can be sorted into categories, so the
>   rules could be category-oriented".

what i mean is that you can have rules that are related to an specific object, for instance

- you have an object that is "platform that moves horizontally", and another that is "plataform that moves vertically". They are different objects, and you can design a rule such as: after a platform that moves horizontally, could not be an exploding platform. Thats a rule involving objects.
- but also, both  "platform that moves horizontally", and another  "plataform that moves vertically" could be considered part of a category, lets say "plataform  that moves". And you can make a rule involving categories, such as "after an exploding platform, could not be a platform that moves".

  - Of course you can design rules object-object, category-category, or object-category.
  - also, keep in mind that categories doesnt need to be something that makes sense in the real world, they could be as arbitrary as you want. For instance you can define a categoy called "crazy platforms" that includes exploding and moving platforms, or you can create a category called "category 1" that includes "moving vertical and breaking" becase for any reason that fits your needs.

---

Also, keep in mind that you need too different things: one is the object factory that i described, to generate a valid world (since it was your main concern) but then you need a fully different system to represent the application life cycle, as Junior Buckeridge describes below.

---

So, to sum up, i know that all this could seem like madness, but i can say that for me,  you are in the middle of one of the more fun and exiting parts of any possible development. And after all, when you put everything together, you will see the world that you imagined, coming up just like magic!

Comment: Thanks! yes, it looks like a state machine is the solution. I drew the state diagram and it looks pretty crazy: pretty much everything is allowed except the cracking platform where I would fall down. I just don't quite see through here...
How would I handle the object generation (spring, propeller, etc)? Please also see my EDIT in the original post

Answer (score 0):

I think you're making a good progress, and it's logical it gets more complicated as you add "magic" to your game.
In my experience, the harder part in a game is to design the rules for the objects, enemies and the hero.

For that, a state machine diagram (such as Mealy or Moore) should grant what you need. if your model grows to be more complicated or you're moving to an event-like model-of-programming, you can try a system based Markov chains.

Once you've mastered that, you start building the main loop of your game, which should go like:

- Initialize

loop:

- Update hero position
- Update enemies position
- Update objects position
- Check for collisions hero-enemies
- Check for collisions hero-objects
- Check for collisions enemies-objects (if needed)
- Check level conditions (win level for instance)

loop until condition breaks

After that you can add some multithreading, but I'd suggest you to make your progress first in functionality and then boost performance.

Keep on.
Regards.

Comment: This... doesn't seem to be an answer to the question. The only part that even touches on it is "use a state machine", with no further explanation.